# Using "unique()" on a vector of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector, unique

I hope this is not a duplicate question, but if it is, feel free to point me in the right direction.

I have a `vector<vector<int> >`.

Is it possible to use `unique()` on this? Something like:

```
vector<vector<int> > myvec;
//blah blah do something to myvec
vector<vector<int> >::interator it = unique(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());
```

Would the range `myvec.begin()` to `it` be unique?

Comment: Of course, this will produce a range of unique `vector<int>` s, not a range of unique `int` s.

Comment: Yeah, I want a range of unique `vector<int>`s. To get a range of unique `int`s I can use unique on each inner vector, and that will work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as long as your vector is sorted. See [unique ()](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique.html) [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) documentation for details.

Here is an example of usage:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector< vector<string> > v;

    v.push_back (vector<string> ());
    v.back ().push_back ("A");

    v.push_back (vector<string> ());
    v.back ().push_back ("A");

    v.push_back (vector<string> ());
    v.back ().push_back ("B");

    for (vector< vector<string> >::iterator it = v.begin (); it != v.end (); ++it)
        for (vector<string>::iterator j = it->begin (), j_end = it->end (); j != j_end; ++j)
            cout << *j << endl;

    cout << "-------" << endl;

    vector< vector<string> >::iterator new_end = unique (v.begin (), v.end ());
    for (vector< vector<string> >::iterator it = v.begin (); it != new_end; ++it)
        for (vector<string>::iterator j = it->begin (), j_end = it->end (); j != j_end; ++j)
            cout << *j << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it should work -- it would call the == operator on two `vector<int>` objects so that should work.

Note that the operator works on groups of duplicates so you may have to sort your outer vector if your duplicates are not grouped already.

Ref: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique.html