# unique() vector of vectors c++

Tags: c++, vector, unique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using “unique()” on a vector of vectors in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773015/using-unique-on-a-vector-of-vectors-in-c)

I'm trying to use the unique algorithm on a vector on vectors.

The error I'm facing is " unique cannot be used as a function"

The problem is that I can't use the command unique() even with normal vectors of int.

The thing I'm trying to do is to erase every repeated vector inside a vector.

so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

void resettaPuntatore(int puntatore, int lunghezza)
{
    puntatore = lunghezza;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v_main;
    vector<int> v_reverse;
    vector<vector<int> > v_contenitore;
    string parola;
    int lunghezza_parola;
    int puntatore;

    cout << "Inserire la parola da permutare.\n";
    cin >> parola;

    lunghezza_parola = parola.length();
    puntatore = lunghezza_parola-1;

    for(int i = 0; i < lunghezza_parola; i++)
    {
        v_main.push_back(i+1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lunghezza_parola; i++)
    {
        v_reverse.push_back(v_main[lunghezza_parola-1-i]);
    }

    while(v_main != v_reverse)
    {
        v_main[puntatore]++;
        if(v_main[puntatore] > lunghezza_parola)
        {
            v_main[puntatore] = 1;
            puntatore--;
        }
        else
        {
            resettaPuntatore(puntatore, lunghezza_parola);
        }
        v_contenitore.push_back(v_main);
    }
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator itr = unique(v_main.begin(), v_main.end());

}
```

And then I would erase all the other items from itr to the end of the vector

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is ``v_main`` and are you ``using namespace std`` somewhere? please post the relevant code.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev it is not a duplicate, since OP reports "unique cannot be used as a function". I am assuming that is some kind of compiler error.

Comment: I edited my question and that is the complete code. It's a permutation exercise. I'm trying to permute a word input by the user in all the possible permutation that can be made on the word. I'm using namespace for std. Everything seems fine, I don't understand what I did wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you don't have the right includes, or you are missing an `std::` somewhere. This example compiles fine:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using std::vector;
  using std::unique;
  vector<vector<int> > v_main;
  v_main.push_back(vector<int>(10));
  v_main.push_back(vector<int>(10, 5));
  v_main.push_back(vector<int>(10, 6));
  vector<vector<int> >::iterator itr = unique(v_main.begin(), v_main.end());
}
```

Comment: My code is practically the same. The only thing I didn't use is:

    using std::vector;
    using std::unique;
I have no idea what the command "using" is for.

Comment: It was a problem of the compiler. My code was correct, just the compiler decided to go crazy. After deleting and creating another project with codeblocks everything became fine again. Thank you for the answer!